# Capacitor Axios FormData Android doesn’t send image files

Tags: android, ionic-framework, axios, multipartform-data, capacitor

I Have an app that it's been compiled to mobile app for Android with Capacitor Ionic.

In a part of this app, the user has to take two pictures to validate it's identity, I'm doing this with this code:

```
// Capacitor imports
import { Camera, CameraResultType, CameraSource } from '@capacitor/camera';

   const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
   
   const takePicture = async (valueToEdit) => {
        try {
            const photo = await Camera.getPhoto({
                resultType: CameraResultType.Uri,
                allowEditing: false,
                source: CameraSource.Camera,
                quality: 60,
                promptLabelCancel: 'Cancelar',
            });

            const blob = await fetch(photo.webPath).then((r) => r.blob());
            const name = new Date().getTime() + '.jpeg';
            const imageTitle = valueToEdit;

            const newImage = {
                itemId: imageTitle,
                img: new File([blob], name, { type: blob.type }),
            };

            // Check if an image with the same itemId already exists
            const imageIndex = images.findIndex(
                (image) => image.itemId === imageTitle
            );
            if (imageIndex !== -1) {
                // Replace the existing image with the new one
                const newImages = [...images];
                newImages[imageIndex] = newImage;
                setImages(newImages);
            } else {
                // Add the new image if it doesn't exist
                setImages((prevImages) => [...prevImages, newImage]);
            }
        } catch (e) {}
    };
```

Then I send the code to the server in this function:

```
// Handle data send
   const handleValidateKyc = () => {
        setErrors({});

        if (documentId === '') {
            setErrors((prevErrors) => ({
                ...prevErrors,
                documentId: 'Ingresa tu número de documento',
            }));
            return;
        }

        if (documentId !== userProfile?.documentId) {
            setErrors((prevErrors) => ({
                ...prevErrors,
                documentId: 'El documento no coincide con el registrado',
            }));
            return;
        }

        const formData = {
            dniImage: images.find((image) => image.itemId === 'dniImage').img,
            selfiWithDNI: images.find((image) => image.itemId === 'selfiWithDNI').img,
            idNumber: documentId,
            idUser: userProfile.id,
        };

        console.log(formData);
        sendKycData(formData);
    };
```

My **sendKycData** function is a redux function and look like this:

```
// Update KYC data.
export const sendKycData = (kycData) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'KYC_VALIDATION_START' });

        const kycFormData = new FormData();

        kycFormData.append('dniImage', kycData.dniImage);
        kycFormData.append('selfiWithDNI', kycData.selfiWithDNI);
        kycFormData.append('idNumber', kycData.idNumber);
        kycFormData.append('idUser', kycData.idUser);

        const sendKycDataConfig = {
            method: 'post',
            maxBodyLength: Infinity,
            url: 'server url',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                Accept: '*/*',
            },
            data: kycFormData,
        };
        
        AxiosInterceptorRequest(sendKycDataConfig)
          .then((resp) => {
                console.log(resp);

                if (resp.status !== 200) {
                    dispatch({
                        type: 'KYC_VALIDATION_ERROR',
                    });

                    dispatch(
                        enqueueSnackbar({
                            // message: resp?.data?.data,
                            message: 'Error en KYC',
                            options: {
                                key: new Date().getTime() + Math.random(),
                                variant: 'error',
                            },
                        })
                    );
                }

                if (resp.status === 200) {
                    dispatch({ type: 'KYC_VALIDATION_SUCCESS' });
                    dispatch({
                        type: 'UPDATE_USER_SUCCESS',
                        payload: resp.data.data,
                    });

                    dispatch(
                        enqueueSnackbar({
                            message: 'KYC Ok',
                            // message: resp?.data?.message,
                            options: {
                                key: new Date().getTime() + Math.random(),
                                variant: 'success',
                            },
                        })
                    );
                }
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log(e);
            });
    };
};
```

On Web it works perfectly but when I compile to mobile for Android with Capacitor, it doesn't send the file images and returns an error that looks like this:

> Unable to find a Capacitor plugin to handle requestCode, trying Cordova plugins 1418078302

It doesn't even print the response

Please could someone guide me to fix this problem??

Comment: Did you find any solutions

Comment: Sadly, researching on the web, I found that for iOS, sending complex data through form data isn't possible or recommended.